# Installing module in virtualenv directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, virtualenv

new to Python and virtualenv so I'm sure this is a noob question, but running into a strange issue when installing a module I've created into a virtualenv folder.

The directory of my module looks like this:

```
VideoUploader/
     VideoUploader/
         videouploader.py #main script
         __init__.py
     bin/
         userinfo.py #this is called by the setup.py file to get info from user via the command line during install
         __init__.py
     docs/
     setup.py
     tests/
         videouploader_tests.py
         __init__.py
```

Here's my setup.py code:

```
import json
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, './bin')
import userinfo

try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {'description': 'VideoUploader',
    'author': '',
    'url': '',
    'download_url': '',
    'author_email': 'alegion@gmail.com',
    'version': '0.1',
    'install_requires': ['nose','feedparser','requests','peewee'],
    'packages': [],
    'scripts': ['bin/userinfo.py'],
    'name': 'VideoUploader'
}


setup(**config)
```

The directory of my virtualenv looks like this:

```
NewProject/
    venv/
        bin/
        include/
        library/
```

I'm unclear on where to drop my module directory so that I can install it in this virtual environment.

I have tried moving it to the `venv` folder, then cd into the `VideoUploader` folder and run `python setup.py install` – but is this the correct location to place the module folder?

After that, from within this directory, I open the Python interpreter and try importing `VideoUploader`. Everything seems fine, however when I try importing a method in the module (which is in the `videouploader.py` file), like `foo = VideoUploader.assignurl()` everything works as expected. But only from within the module folder `VideoUploader`, so clearly it's not installed correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please add setup.py source

Comment: @svfat added setup.py code

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can run `setup.py install` from any directory, it isn't necessary to put in in venv directory. The files will be copied to right places automatically. Regarding errors on module import, are you sure that you activated your virtualenv (run `source venv/bin/activate`) You should do that before installing.

Comment: From within the `NewProject` directory, I ran `source venv/bin/activate` and everything looks fine. I then `cd` into the `VideoUploader` directory with the `setup.py file` and run `python setup.py install`  and everything looks fine, my module install executes as expected. I then cd out of `VideoUploder` directory back into the `venv` folder, open the Python interpreter and try and import the `VideoUploader` module and get an import error `ImportError: No module named FacebookVideoUploader` — what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @SeanJarp try change the value of  'packages' to ['VideoUploader']

Comment: Ok, edited `packages` to `['VideoUploader']`. Now, when I cd into `venv` and start the Python interpreter, I can import `VideoUploader` but not any of the methods. Only when I cd into `VideoUploader` can I access the methods in the `videouploader.py`